# why does my template literal doesn't work in javascript in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm beginner with java script, and I am practicing with mdn document.

the code I wrote is working differently with what is written on mdn as below.

```
    "use strict";

    let bigInt = 34321321321;
    console.log("value: ${bigInt}");

    let a = 5;
    let b = 10;
    console.log("fifteen is ${a+b}");
```

I just added script tag on index.html, which is default html file.

[image]

I did it on google chrome.

what could be the problem?

Comment: shouldn't the code be in typescript?

Comment: Template literals use backticks (`) , not normal quotes (").

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo since OP used `"` instead of `\``

Answer (score 1):

To use `${variable}` you should use back tick ` not double qoutes `""`.

Back ticks use variables with `${}`. If you don't use back ticks then the variable should be applied like below,

```
let variable = 123213;

console.log("The variable is" + variable);
```

If `${}` is used then,

```
let variable = 123213;

// backticks are used without double qoutes(")
console.log(`The variable is ${variable}`);
```

Also there is [a MDN reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I confused back tick with single quotes, so vs code automatically changed it into double quotes!

Comment: @JungHwanPark You're welcome. VS code helps users code better :) Hope your nice coding journey!